# Cannot remove char 0x0000 from NVARCHAR column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, collation, unicode

So, I know all about the Replace function and a bug with char(0).

I have a column (`NVARCHAR(128)`) that has some `NCHAR(0x0000)` characters from a bad import.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

The collation for the column is: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

I have tried all the stuff online that I can possibly find, and NOTHING will get the stinking char(0) characters out of the column.

Here's my latest attempt, with BAFFLING (bug in sql server?) results.

I have a function that loops through each char and replaces 0x0000 with a specific char.

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ReplaceCharZero
(
  @testString NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @charToReplaceWith NCHAR(1) = ' '
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @i INT = 1 ,
        @fixedString NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    WHILE @i <= LEN(@testString)
        BEGIN
            IF SUBSTRING(@testString, @i, 1) = CHAR(0x00)
                BEGIN
                    --PRINT 'Found' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR)
                    SET @fixedString = @fixedString + @charToReplaceWith         
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    --PRINT 'NOT Found' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR)
                    SET @fixedString = @fixedString
                        + SUBSTRING(@testString, @i, 1)
                END
            SET @i = @i + 1
        END
    RETURN @fixedString               
END
```

And here's what I do to test:

```sql
BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @ShortDescription NVARCHAR(128), @SupplierId INT, @Language CHAR(2)

    SELECT TOP 1 @ShortDescription = ShortDescription,
                 @SupplierId = SupplierID,
                 @Language = Language
    FROM   Supplier_Multilingual
    WHERE  ShortDescription LIKE '%' +  CHAR(0x00) + '%'

    SET @ShortDescription =  REPLACE(dbo.ReplaceCharZero(@ShortDescription, ' '), '-', ' ')

    UPDATE dbo.Supplier_MultiLingual
    SET    ShortDescription = NULL 
    WHERE  SupplierID = @SupplierId
    AND    Language = @Language

    UPDATE dbo.Supplier_MultiLingual
    SET    ShortDescription = dbo.ReplaceCharZero(@ShortDescription, '') 
    WHERE  SupplierID = @SupplierId
    AND    Language = @Language

    SELECT *
    FROM   Supplier_Multilingual
    WHERE  SupplierId = @SupplierId
    AND    Language = @Language
    AND    ShortDescription LIKE '%' +  CHAR(0x00) + '%'

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

In my test, I grab the column as a variable, I run my function on it to strip out the `0x0000`, then I update the original column with a `NULL`, then I update it to my fixed variable, and then I run a query to see if `0x0000` chars still exist, which they do.

Comment: How do you KNOW the null is not being replaced?

Comment: It turns out i did NOT know. I was trusting the last statement that was looking for '%' + Char(0x00) + '%'. When it was really just finding spaces, and even worse since char(0x00) is undefined for some collations, it will convert the string to '%%' which matches all

Comment: I have a feeling that converting the original string or result of `SUBSTRING()` to `varbinary` could help.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Converting to `VARBINARY` is not necessary. Please see my [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122032/30859) for details :-).

Comment: @ttomsen Not sure if you saw my [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122032/30859), but you definitely do not need a UDF to remove `CHAR(0x00)` / `NCHAR(0x0000)` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CHAR(0)` appears to be converted to a space, or `CHAR(32)`.

The following demonstrates the problem:

```
DECLARE @Data NVARCHAR(255);
SELECT @Data = 'this is a test' + CHAR(0) + 'of null';
DECLARE @i INT;
SET @i = 1;
DECLARE @txt NVARCHAR(255);
WHILE @i < LEN(@Data)
BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@Data, @i, 1) = CHAR(0) 
    BEGIN
        SET @txt = 'found a null char at position ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),@i);        
        RAISERROR (@txt, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
    END
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I found this too. So the checking query at the end that looks to see if there are any more char(0) finds spaces and tells me incorrectly that their are 0x00 chars remaining in the string. I was chasing a goose :(

Comment: More info.. in some collations it just translates the 0 char to undefined which in my case was leading to false positives.

Comment: more info for folks, my function up there will remove the 0x00 and replace it, but you'll NEVER know because you can't go back and check it. bad sql server.

Comment: @ttomsen and Max: The `CHAR(0)` is not actually being converted to a space. The "character" within the `@Data` variable is still `0x0000`, but `NCHAR(0)` can equate to it when using a non-binary collation (i.e. one that does _not_ end in `_BIN` or `_BIN2`, though `_BIN` has been deprecated for a while now). Please see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 7):

A bug in the `REPLACE` function? Or in SQL Server in general? I'm not so sure about that. The only "issue" here is merely not fully understanding how string comparisons are handled.

Collations define how certain characters will compare against other characters. Sometimes there are rules about certain combinations of characters equating to one or more other characters. And there are rules about characters such as `0x00` (null) and `0x20` (space) equating to each other or other characters. And, to make life more interesting, there are a few nuances specific to `VARCHAR` data using a SQL Server Collation (i.e. one starting with `SQL_`), as the following example shows:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE('VARCHAR with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'+CHAR(0)+'Matches', CHAR(0),
               ': ' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS);
SELECT REPLACE(N'NVARCHAR with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'+NCHAR(0)+N'Matches', NCHAR(0),
               N': ' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS);
SELECT REPLACE('VARCHAR with Latin1_General_100_CI_AS'+CHAR(0)+'Matches', CHAR(0),
               ': ' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS);
SELECT REPLACE(N'NVARCHAR with Latin1_General_100_CI_AS'+NCHAR(0)+N'Matches', NCHAR(0),
               N': ' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS);
```

Returns:

```
VARCHAR with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS: Matches

NVARCHAR with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

VARCHAR with Latin1_General_100_CI_AS

NVARCHAR with Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
```

---

So let's take a look at this behavior using queries based on the ones found in @Max's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82094/cannot-remove-char-0x00-from-nvarchar-column/82097#82097). I added the `N` prefix to the string literals and to the `CHAR(0)`, and I also added an extra `NCHAR(0)` just to make the next part easier to see. And I added queries to show the actual Code Points being used (to prove that the `0x0000` values are really in there, and a call to `REPLACE()` to see if that really has a bug in it).

```sql
DECLARE @Data NVARCHAR(255);
SELECT @Data = N'this is' + NCHAR(0) + N'a test' + NCHAR(0) + N'of null';

SELECT @Data;
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(50), @Data);
SELECT REPLACE(@Data, NCHAR(0), N'~');
```

> this is
>
> 0x7400680069007300200069007300**0000**610020007400650073007400**0000**6F00660020006E0075006C006C00
>
> this is

The first result shows that the string ends just after the "is" due to `(null)` termination. The second result shows the underlying codes, and I emphasized the two instances of the `0x0000` character. The third result shows that the `REPLACE` function doesn't seem to match the `0x0000` character to the `NCHAR(0)` that is passed in.

But should we be expecting that `NCHAR(0)` would be matching here? We can effectively disable all of the equivalence rules that are usually applied to string comparisons by forcing a binary collation. We will use a `_BIN2` collation since the `_BIN` collations are deprecated and shouldn't be used unless you have a specific need for them.

Add the following query to the set above and re-run the batch.

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(@Data, NCHAR(0) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2, N'~');
```

You should get the following additional result:

> this is~a test~of null

So the `REPLACE` function does in fact work, and this was tested on both SQL Server 2008 R2, SP3 as well as SQL Server 2012 SP2.

---

Ok, so that only addressed the issue of `REPLACE` not working with `NCHAR(0)`, but did not address `NCHAR(0)` equating to a space (i.e. `NCHAR(32)` or `NCHAR(0x20)`).

Now we will use an adaptation of the main query from @Max's answer. I again added an extra `NCHAR(0)` to the test string (really just replaced the space at position 8 with it), and I added the Code Point of the matching character to the `RAISERROR` message.

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
DECLARE @Data NVARCHAR(255);
SELECT @Data = N'this is' + NCHAR(0) + N'a test' + NCHAR(0) + N'of null';

DECLARE @i INT,
        @CodePoint INT;
SET @i = 1;

WHILE @i < LEN(@Data)
BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@Data, @i, 1) = NCHAR(0) --COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
    BEGIN
        SET @CodePoint = UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@Data, @i, 1));
        RAISERROR (N'Found a NULL char (Code Point = %d) at position: %d',
                   10, 1, @CodePoint, @i) WITH NOWAIT;
    END;
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;
```

This query (with the `COLLATE` clause still commented out) will return:

```
Found a NULL char (Code Point = 32) at position: 5
Found a NULL char (Code Point = 0) at position: 8
Found a NULL char (Code Point = 32) at position: 10
Found a NULL char (Code Point = 0) at position: 15
Found a NULL char (Code Point = 32) at position: 18
```

These are the same positions reported in @Max's test, but now it shows what Code Point it is matching in each case. And yes, it is equating to both `32` and `0`.

Now, uncomment the `COLLATE` clause and re-run it. It will return:

```
Found a NULL char (Code Point = 0) at position: 8
Found a NULL char (Code Point = 0) at position: 15
```

Another way to accomplish this, and without using the `COLLATE` clause, is to change the `IF` statement to be:

```sql
IF ( UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@Data, @i, 1)) = 0 )
```

Of course, neither of these two fixes -- the `WHILE` loop using either the `COLLATE` clause or the `UNICODE()` function -- are needed to address the original problem of removing the `0x0000` characters from the input data since the simple `REPLACE` (using the `COLLATE` clause) handles that.

---

**Summary:**

- If you are wanting to replace / remove characters from a string, there is no need to use a loop. The `REPLACE` function works just fine as long as you specify a `_BIN2` collation for at least one of the 3 input parameters via the `COLLATE` keyword (and technically it doesn't matter which binary collation since binary collations only compare the numeric Code Point values).
- If needing to test for a particular Code Point (such as in a loop as shown above), then it is probably fastest to use the `UNICODE()` function since that just reports what values are actually there. This should be faster than using the `COLLATE` keyword since that has to do more work.
- If needing to test for a series of Code Points / characters, then use the `COLLATE` keyword, specifying a `_BIN2` binary collation.

Comment: +1. A very nice detailed answer. I didn't think about setting/changing collation, I thought about `IF CONVERT(varbinary(2), SUBSTRING(@Data, @i, 1), 0) = convert(varbinary(2), CHAR(0), 0)`. Your variant with collation looks better.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Thanks. I just added a "summary" section to help navigate these types of scenarios. Regarding your thought, you don't need the right side of that equation since it is effectively a constant of `0x0000`. But you should use `VARBINARY(4)` since Supplementary Characters are a pair of 2-byte codes (it won't help for 00 but is a good habit to get into). So you would just do `IF ( CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), SUBSTRING(@Data, @i, 1)) = 0x0000 )`. But then that's no different than what I showed using the `UNICODE` function, except for getting a hex / BINARY value instead of a decimal / INT.